# Force newly created directory and files to inherit permissions from parent directory

Tags: linux, permissions

How to make newly created files and directories inherit permissions of parent directory?
E.g.,
Parent

```
drwxrwx--- parentdir
```

Then the children should have -

```
-rwxrwx--- childFile
drwxrwx--- childDir
```

I am aware of setgid, but it only changes the group id to owner's group id and not replicating the exact permissions from the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to define "default ACLs" using `setfacl`. This works not only for named user/group ACLs, but also for the basic unnamed permission bits:

```
setfacl -d -m "u::rwx,g::rwx,o::-" parentdir
```

Note that you cannot force new files to be executable; even if the ACL grants +rwx, the newly created file will still have a `mask::` entry limiting it to just +rw, because this is *usually* what most people want, and because it is not possible to have different default ACLs for child files than child folders.

(Also note that once a file or folder has ACLs, trying to change its "group" rwx permissions via chmod will actually change the *mask* entry that affects all ACLs at once – not just the unnamed group entry. This is generally good, because it lets you clearly see in `ls -l` if a file has write rights granted to anyone at all, but it also means that to change just the unnamed group access you'll now need `setfacl -m g::???`.)

This does not affect the setgid bit, which can be changed using `chmod g±s` as usual.

---

*(Also note that unlike Windows or NFS4 "inheritable" ACLs, the POSIX "default" ACLs only take effect when the item is created, but the child item permissions are *not* recalculated when the parent's "default" ACLs change.)*

For more information:

- [POSIX Access Control Lists on Linux](http://web.archive.org/web/20141226013058/http://users.suse.com/%7Eagruen/acl/linux-acls/online/)
- "ACL ENTRIES" in [setfacl(1)](https://manpages.debian.org/setfacl.1.en.html#ACL_ENTRIES)

Comment: How do we use the command if we want setgid bit set, E.g., 2770, using the setfacl command which you gave ?

Comment: setfacl only deals with general permissions - not with the setgid bit. If you want the setgid bit, set it via chmod as usual.

Comment: Do we need to follow any order? Like, run ```chmod``` first and then run ```setfacl``` .

Comment: For setuid/setgid, no, the order should not matter. The order only matters if trying to change the general "group" permissions (that is `rwx`). E.g. trying to use `chmod g-w` while ACLs are present would alter the ACL "mask" entry rather than the "group::" entry, but `chmod g+s` would still set setgid as usual because it's never controlled via ACLs.

Comment: It works as per my expectation, Thank You so much !